# Booleans in If Statements in Python

Tags: python, variables, if-statement, boolean, global-variables

So, I've been coding for a Python 'computer software', one where you basically have a log-in username and password that can be edited. I tried to add a feature that allows you to 'remove' the password, (but is more like skipping it) but it won't work. Here is the code for the **skipping** procedure:

```
def Access1(): 
    print("Input first name")
    print("")
    answer = raw_input()
    if(answer.lower() == username and PasswordSkip == True):
        print("")
        print("Access granted")
        List1()
    if(answer.lower() == username and PasswordSkip == False):
        print("")
        print("Access granted")
        Access2()
```

*Note that `Access2()` is the function where a password is needed to continue, and `List1()` is the main menu of the system.

Here is where the boolean is set to `True`:

```
def PasswordRemove():
    print("")
    print("Are you sure you want to remove your password, <yes> or <no>?")
    print("")
    key = raw_input()
    if(key.lower() == "yes"):
        PasswordSkip = True
        print("")
        print("Ok, your password has been removed.")
        print("")
        List1()
    elif(key.lower() == "no"):
        DetailsChange()
    else:
        DetailsChange()
```

And here is how I define and globalise `PasswordSkip`:

```
PasswordSkip = False

def Startup():
    global PasswordSkip
```

(the function goes on longer, but has no involvement in the boolean.)

If you need any more infor ation on my code, I'm able to give it to you.

So, when I run my code, it overlooks the if statement about the boolean. If the boolean is `True`, it should go to a different function. However, it skips the statement because it brings up `Access2()` (the password function).

Answers aren't urgently needed, but thanks.

Comment: `global` statements set the scope of a name *per function*. `global PasswordSkip` in `Startup` won't alter the scope of the name in a different function.

Comment: btw, are you sure you want to grant access in either case `PasswordSkip == True` and `PasswordSkip == False`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fragment

```
def Startup():
    global PasswordSkip
```

does not declare `PasswordSkip` to be global everywhere.  It declares that within **this** function, references to setting `PasswordSkip` should be taken to be the global variable `PasswordSkip` rather than some local variable.

Now in the function `PasswordRemove`, you do not declare that `PasswordSkip` is a global to be brought into scope.  Thus statements like `PasswordSkip = True` are setting a **local** variable `PasswordSkip`

Comment: Oh, I finally understand. Thanks so much for explaining it, the skip procedure works.